# How to enable parameter name hints for Kotlin in Android Studio Bumblebee?

Tags: parameters, code-hinting, android-studio-bumblebee

[image]

I want to enable parameter hints as to the above image for Kotlin in Android Studio Bumblebee. But settings have only the below options. Is there any way to enable this option?

[image]